# how to distinguish retweets from originals in twitter search request

Tags: api, twitter

I'm trying to understand how to distinguish retweets from their original in the [twitter search request](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search):

```
{ created_at: 'Mon Mar 06 05:24:24 +0000 2017',
   id: 838621263144890400,
   id_str: '838621263144890370',
   text: 'developerWorks: Check out the latest dW newsblast TODAY! Learn about new tech toys, chatbots, and IBM Cloud.',
   truncated: false,
   entities: [Object],
   metadata: [Object],
   source: '<a href="https://ifttt.com" rel="nofollow">IFTTT</a>',
   in_reply_to_status_id: null,
   in_reply_to_status_id_str: null,
   in_reply_to_user_id: null,
   in_reply_to_user_id_str: null,
   in_reply_to_screen_name: null,
   user: [Object],
   geo: null,
   coordinates: null,
   place: null,
   contributors: null,
   is_quote_status: false,
   retweet_count: 0,
   favorite_count: 0,
   favorited: false,
   retweeted: false,
   possibly_sensitive: false,
   lang: 'en' },
 { created_at: 'Mon Mar 06 05:22:17 +0000 2017',
   id: 838620728446578700,
   id_str: '838620728446578688',
   text: 'RT developerWorks: Check out the latest dW newsblast TODAY! Learn about new tech toys, chatbots, and IBM Cloud.',
   truncated: false,
   entities: [Object],
   metadata: [Object],
   source: '<a href="https://ifttt.com" rel="nofollow">IFTTT</a>',
   in_reply_to_status_id: null,
   in_reply_to_status_id_str: null,
   in_reply_to_user_id: null,
   in_reply_to_user_id_str: null,
   in_reply_to_screen_name: null,
   user: [Object],
   geo: null,
   coordinates: null,
   place: null,
   contributors: null,
   is_quote_status: false,
   retweet_count: 0,
   favorite_count: 0,
   favorited: false,
   retweeted: false,
   possibly_sensitive: false,
   lang: 'en' }
```

Could someone advice me something? I can see only an information if this post was retweeted but not if this's a retweet itself. I can check whether `text` starts with `RT` but it looks like a bad solution for me.

Comment: Check for retweeted flag https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets. Although from your sample dataset there is no difference between tweet and retweet apart from RT flag that you have mentioned

Comment: @YamanJain i think that `retweeted` means that current tweet was retweeted. that's not what i need :(

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen `retweeted` flag actually set to `true` in any API responses. 
I believe all retweets will have a `retweeted_status` field.